# Need help understanding how GCC compilation work on linux and macOS

Tags: c

I recently obtained a macbook so I started learning how to develop project on macOS, to do so, I tried to compile a finished project I made on linux, the .o file got created easily but I had trouble with the executable.

Here is the line :

```
gcc -Wall -g -O2 `sdl2-config --cflags` head.h -o game.out mainSDL.o container.o update.o user.o -O2 `sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL2_image 

clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make: *** [game.out] Error 1
```

(I have sdl2 installed on this pc)

This line was working perfectly under archlinux.

This project compile easily with some basic command like :

```
gcc container.c mainSDL.c user.c update.c -lSDL2
```

But I would like to understand what's going on,

Why this error with this line ?

Thanks for your help

Edit : Finally the problem came from this bad makefile which had some useless line and a header in it.

Comment: Why are you compiling a header?

Comment: Note that normally on MacOS, `gcc` is a symlink to `clang`.

Comment: I'm not the one who made this makefile but I was asking myself the same question, but as it was working on my archlinux I thought it wasn't the problem here and when I remove it I get another error ( clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 )

Comment: Oh, so it's not the same compiler, it may explain some things, I guess I should search what are the difference between clang and gcc then

Comment: Run the command `sdl2-config --cflags` on both systems and update the question with the output.

Comment: Also, please remove the second question and post it as a new one. The two questions does not have much to do with each other, making this question to broad.

Comment: You could also try making gcc a symbolic link to clang on your Arch system to see if you get similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`sdl2-config --cflags` head.h
```

These bits are suspect. Passing a header file to the compiler is almost certainly wrong.

The rest of the line has linking options, but `--cflags` spits out compile options. From the looks of it, compiling's already complete.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned this part and it finally compile, so I guess the problem was a bad makefile, but I don't know why gcc accept this..

Answer (score 0):

You posted

> gcc -Wall -g -O2 `sdl2-config --cflags` head.h -o game.out mainSDL.o container.o update.o user.o -O2 `sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL2_image

I'll try to explain the command line, parameter by parameter:

- `-Wall` means to the compiler to activate all kinds of warnings.  Warnings normally don't mean to stop the compilation, errors do, so activating them all will give a finer approach of the code errors you can be making in the code.
- `-g`  means to include debug info (source line references) in the executable, to be able to do source debugging.
- `-O2` means to do second level optimisations.  This normally makes your code more difficult to debug, as the source line references don't match well with the binary code.  It is normal to do `-O0` (meaning no optimisation at all) when debugging.
- `sdl2-config --cflags` is a command execute by the shell that output the compiling options of the `sdl2` library.  It normally emits the `-I` options necessary to find the `#include` files.  It is enclosed in backticks (sorry, but don't know how to show them escaped in code mode) to make the shell to replace the parameter with the output of the `sdl2-config` command.
- `head.h` is an include file.... normally you get that file `#include`d from other files, so it is a mistake to compile it directly.  You have to take it away, as it is not intended to be compiled separately.
- `-o game.out` means to call the output executable `game.out`.  This names the output file.  When you are compiling-only (not linking) separate sources (by use of `-c` option) and you specify multiple files to compile, it is an error (the one you mention) to specify a single output filename, as each output binary is called after its source, by changing the `.c` suffix by a `.o` one.
- `mainSDL.o`, `container.o`, `update.o`, `user.o` are object modules, already compiled (these are used only when you are linking a final executable)
- `-O2` is repeated.
- `sdl2-config --libs`  this is executed by the shell and its output is substituted as the link parameters necessary to be able to link with the `sdl2` library.  It generates the `-L` paths necessary to find the library location.
- `-lSDL2_image` this means to use the `SDL2_image` library at link time.

Well, it is fairly bad.  The `sdl2-donfig --cflags` is used to compile only and probably generates (you can try by executing the following command:

```
sdl2-config --cflags
```

in the command line by itself), you'll see what options it is giving to the compiler.  Most probably, it generates a `-c` option to compile-only, so this makes all the `.o` and the `-o` options unnecessary, and compilation has to be made in two steps (one to compile, one to link)

`sdl2-config --libs` will append all the `-l` libraries to the link phase, so it is not necessary to add a `-lSDL2_image` option.

I suggest to compile your program to use (after trying to guess what you have posted only) the following commands:

```
gcc -Wall -g -O0 `sdl2-config --cflags` mainSDL.c container.c update.c user.c
```

(or individually for each source file) to compile-only all source files, and then

```
gcc -g -O0 -o game.out mainSDL.o container.o update.o user.o `sdl2-config --libs`
```

to link the result in a final executable.

But I know nothing about your source files, so I don't know if this will give you the correct results.